# "I'm working day tomorrow and night the day after tomorrow."

Tags: word-usage

An example from [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-you-work-on-daytime-at-night-now.3753522/#post-19164226):
**(1)** *I'm working days this week and nights next week*.

I'm interested in using the word "*days*" here:
firstly it means one of the parts which a 24-hour period is divided into;
secondly it answers the question "when", being used without any preposition:
-*When are you working this week and when next week*?
-*I'm working days this week and nights next week*.

To better understand such a usage, I decided to make up some similar variants of (1).
**(2)** *I'm working day this week and night next week*. — is it correct?
**(3)** *I'm working day tomorrow and night the day after tomorrow*. — is it correct?

Comment: *Days*, as it's used in your example, refers to a *work-shift* or just *shift* (i.e. The part of the 24 hour period a worker is expected to be at work).  These *work-shifts*  do no necessarily match the daylight definitions of days and nights.  A day shift might be from 6 a.m. to 3 p.m. and a night shift may run from 11 p.m. to 6 a.m.  *Shifts* are also often called first, second, and third shift.

Answer (score 2):

The thread on Word Reference was started by a question about shift working. *I'm working days this week* means *This week, I will be working the day shift*.

People who work night shifts usually do so for a period of time so that they can establish a pattern of sleeping in the daytime. Someone who had to work a single night shift in an emergency would probably say "I have to work a night shift tomorrow", not "I'm working night".

So - no, it isn't natural to say "I'm working day" or "I'm working night" in the singular.

Comment: Can I use "days" without attaching it to work-shifts? For example we have the next sentence (-[link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-means-for-rejecting-a-waiver-are-at-best-opaque.3675597/#post-18742698)-): _People who work night shift and sleep days often want totally opaque blackout curtains for their bedroom windows to keep the room dark while they sleep_. Can I say it without "working night shift": "_People who sleep days often want totally opaque blackout curtains for their bedroom windows._" ? Thanks.